# Python Tkinter Checkbutton Issue

Tags: python, button, checkbox, tkinter

I have a two very simple check buttons, whose variables I am saving within a list (varss), and one button. But I do not understand why when I call var_states (by pressing the button), I cannot get the off/on values. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
from Tkinter import *

def run():
    # create the root and the canvas
    root = Tk()
    canvas = Canvas(root, width=300, height=200)
    canvas.pack()
    class Struct: pass
    canvas.data = Struct()
    # canvas.data.givenIngredients = set()

    prefInput(canvas)
    # and launch the app
    root.mainloop()

def var_states(varss):
    for var in varss:
        var.get()

def prefInput(canvas):
    master = Tk()
    var1, var2 = IntVar(), IntVar()
    Checkbutton(master, text="male", variable=var1).grid(row=1, sticky=W)
    varss = [var1, var2]
    Checkbutton(master, text="female", variable=var2).grid(row=2, sticky=W)
    Button(master, text='Show', command=lambda:var_states(varss)).grid(row=4, sticky=W, pady=4)

run()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have created two Tcl interpreters, one with each call to `Tk()`.  Each Tcl interpreter has variables distinct from every other Tcl interpreter.

The first interpreter created becomes the default interpreter for a Tkinter object which does not explicitly relate itself to an existing interpreter (for instance, by passing a widget in that interpreter to its 'master' in its constructor)

You probably did not intend to create two interpreters, so for starters don't execute

```
master = Tk()
```

in prefInput.  Instead, use the `canvas` argument as the first argument to your Checkbutton calls (replacing `master`), and also use it in the calls to `IntVar`: `var1, var2 = IntVar(canvas), IntVar(canvas)`.  (if you do want an additional window within your application, use Tkinter.Toplevel instead of Tkinter.Tk for the second window)

Finally, for testing I changed your `Var_states` function so that it printed more information:

```
def var_states(varss):
    print "var_states", varss
    for var in varss:
        print var, var.get()
```

The final program then reads:

```
from Tkinter import *

def run():
    # create the root and the canvas
    root = Tk()
    canvas = Canvas(root, width=300, height=200)
    canvas.pack()
    class Struct: pass
    canvas.data = Struct()
    # canvas.data.givenIngredients = set()

    prefInput(canvas)
    # and launch the app
    root.mainloop()

def var_states(varss):
    print "var_states", varss
    for var in varss:
        print var, var.get()

def prefInput(canvas):
    var1, var2 = IntVar(canvas), IntVar(canvas)
    Checkbutton(canvas, text="male", variable=var1).grid(row=1, sticky=W)
    varss = [var1, var2]
    Checkbutton(canvas, text="female", variable=var2).grid(row=2, sticky=W)
    Button(canvas, text='Show', command=lambda:var_states(varss)).grid(row=4, sticky=W, pady=4)

run()
```